# Re-order an array

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsuserdefaults

I have a list of bookmarks stored in NSUserDefaults. For each bookmark entry I retreive data from a sqlite database. I then create an array of these bookmarks. Each bookmark in the array is represented as a person object.

How ca I re-order the array to sort by the persons first name?

Comment: Does the database store the person's first name? If it does all you need to do is tack on an `ORDER BY first_name` to your query.

Comment: When I query the database i query for each person - one at a time.

I'm just trying to re-order the array. The database does contain the first name, but to sort via the database I would need to loop through the NSUserDefault array and build a list of all the bookmark ids, then query the database for all id's ordering by name.

Just thought it might be user to re-order the array some how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort an NSArray you would use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`, `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, or one of the other [sorting variants](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12).